How can I wire up a USB-C connector for 12v (4A) of fixed voltage
I have an SBC (Radxa Rock 5B) that accepts PD as power supply, but it's buggy and often too slow to negotiate a voltage before the power supply cuts and we end up in a boot loop.
But, it can also accept just a fixed 12V supply through its USB-C port. No PD negotiation.
I'd like to build this power supply, with the minimal soldering, since I don't need the data transfer.

I understand that buying a pigtail USB-C rated for USB2 would only allow 3A. Am I correct I thinking that simple wiring solution would be a recipe for a fire?

To use a USB 3.1 plug, should I just be wiring the positive of my 12V DC power supply to pins A4, B4, A9 and B9 with the negative to A1, B1, A12 and B12 based on this diagram.



If it matters or helps to paint a picture, the power supply I'm looking at using is something like this LED Driver which delivers constant 12V with a 100W capacity (I'm looking to wire a couple of other things to the second rail to make a bit more use of those 100W)

I'm thinking that using a straight 12V supply with no PD negotiation violates USB standards.

A 5A rated USB cable would handle 5A, you don't need to buy a 3A rated cable. You also should not forcibly provide 12V without negotiation as at some point someone will plug something irreplaceable to the 12V accidentally which fries up immediately and you lose important data or work, such as a phone or laptop.

If you don't plan to sell this power supply on open market, you can wire it however you want. BTW, what do you mean under "before the power supply cuts"? The power either is negotiated to certain contract, or not (remains at "Safe5V"). The system is not supposed to start until the right contract is set.  What do you mean "cuts"?

@Ale..chenski thanks for the comment. I’ve lost the link with the details, but the PD negotiation times out and returns to 5v. So my SBC restarts. And the process starts again.

And. I have no intention of selling it.

@Justme I know that risk. But the cable will be inside a box and only used for this one device. I need a usb connector as that’s what my SBC uses - otherwise I’d use something less easy to accidentally connect to generic devices. Thanks.

@VoltageSpike yeah. I know. But, will the device get 12v - regardless of the spec.

"and returns to 5v" - Do you mean that the voltage went initially up, but then came back to default? Did you try to capture VBUS voltage during this process with an oscilloscope?  Also, did you try any other (different brand/type) PD Type-C power source?

I tried a bunch. And eventually found one that works. It’s an old anker and doesn’t quite meet the spec (only handles 1.75A at 20v - which is what it’s currently pulling - instead of the recommended 2A) so I expect this won’t be a long term solution once I start adding devices.

Notably, the anker is also IQ3 (as opposed to PD)

So instead of trying random PSUs until I get one, I thought to wire one up.

I have a multimeter but I’ve not broken that out to witness the negotiations in action. I’m basing my assumption on the many many reports of this kind of failure to negotiate a voltage with this chipset

Thanks for your help so far

I have also ordered a buck/boost and the LED driver to build a PD power supply. But I was wondering if I can just do away with the negotiating and wire up 12V directly.

@Ale..chenski I found the original ref to the “negotiating too slow” The USB Power Delivery negotiation to get the needed power, is done by the OS kernel and may happen too late, causing endless restarts.
See the FAQ More context: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg239175.html

Good find about the kernel. Here is a fundamental conceptual circular issue: you cannot start negotiation for power while you have no necessary power- dead circle here. PD negotiation are usually done with a dedicated PD controller (something like a low-power ARM32 processor and well functional at Safe5V), not by the full-blown kernel of main processor.

You can directly operate radxa Rock 5B with a 12 V supply. I am already operating one. Your wiring connections are correct.

Power requirement 12V at 4 A is a very unusual profile for Power Delivery. The baseline boundary for the original PD standard is 3A. If the device needs a current above that, a 20V level is required.

In graphics form,, all from PD 3.1 specs:

No wonder the "Radxa Rock 5B" fails to negotiate proper power profile from a standard PD supply. Therefore, your only option is to hardwire the Type-C connector for 12V and forget about PD.

PD negotiations follow these profiles: ROCK 5B supports USB Type-C PD 2.0 with 9V/2A, 12V/2A, 15V/2A and 20V/2A.

The 12v 4A recommendation is for non-negotiated direct power. It’s draw whatever current it needs based on power requirements of attached devices.

I figured that was my only option.
